# Access a variable in a Class function from in another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I cannot get the code to run because of the scope of the frame initialized by MyApp. Here is a condensed sample app that demonstrates my problem

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.InitWindow()
        return True

    def InitWindow(self):
        frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Travis's sample problem app")
        nameField = wx.TextCtrl(frame)

        clickbtn = wx.Button(frame, 0, label="click me")
        frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickedAction, clickbtn)
        frame.Show()

    def clickedAction(self, e):
        #Here we will get an error: "object has no attribute 'nameField'"
        print self.nameField.GetString()
        #what am I doing wrong?

app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

Why is the `nameField` out of scope for the function that tries to use it?

Comment: Without some code, your question is "Stuff doesn't work. Why not?"

Comment: Please just ask about your programming problem, in detail. We don't need any of this background information.

Comment: *update - added code

Comment: This code runs for me. Maybe you should be posting what error message you are getting or otherwise specify what you mean by "app does not run"

Comment: self.nameField has not been declared, and is different from nameField.  There are other problems as well.

Comment: Also, you may want GetValue instead of GetString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance variable declarations are being declared as local variables that your function can't access. You would instead declare them with `self.` in the init to make their scope include the whole instance.

Change to like this:

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
   def __init__(self):  #<-- runs when we create MyApp
        #stuff here
        self.nameField = wx.TextCtrl(frame)  #<--scope is for all of MyApp
        #stuff

    def clickedAction(self, e):
        #stuff
app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

You could read more about the difference between class variables and instance variables [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Comment: Is there no way in python to declare a variable within a function created in a class definition? In my example program above, can I not create the nameField variable there but as a global variable?

Comment: @TravisCook you can do such things, though your IDE/compiler will probably generate a warning for "`declared instance variable outside of __init__`". I have added a link to the end of the answer with some more info and you could also learn about global variables and create a separate question about those if you need.